# Why is my logic incorrect for my selection sort recursion program?

Tags: c

So my recursion selection sort calls two functions max_index and the swap and at the same time it should recursively swap the stuff, but for some reason it seems to break and explode into fire for certain arrays like the one I have set in main. Does anyone know why this is so? Can someone explain and show me why this isn't working?

```
int max_index(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if ( start >= end ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( end - start == 1 ) {
        return start;
    }
    else {
        int greatest = max_index(arr, start + 1, end);
        if( arr[start] > arr[greatest])
        {
            return start;
        }
        else
        {
            return greatest;
        }

    }
}
void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=temp;
}

void rec_ssort(int arr[], int len) {
        int start = 0;
        int last = len - 1;
        //int n = len;
        int maxindex = max_index(arr, start, last);
        //if(arr[maxindex]>0 || arr[maxindex]<n)
        {
            if(arr[maxindex]>arr[last])
            {
                swap(arr, maxindex, last);
                return rec_ssort(arr, last);
            }
            if(arr[maxindex] == arr[last])
            {
                return rec_ssort(arr, last);
            }
         }
}



int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int arr[7] = {2,3,4,1,5,6,7};
    int start = 0;
    int end = 7;
    int stuff = 5;
    rec_ssort(arr, end);
    for(i = 0; i<7; i++)
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you start with a small input set, and then with that step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see what happens.

Comment: Also, for the length of the array, you pass the last index instead of the length.

Comment: What debugger do you mean? I am on linux right now and I haven't learned anything about debuggers.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: My school computers aren't letting me download this, but when I look at the flow of logic I don't see what could be wrong with my selection sort recursive algorithm.

Comment: Then I suggest you first write out the algorithm on paper, and step through it on paper. Something you probably should have started with. Remember to check for larger, equal *and* smaller values. Hint: You don't have to use C statements and keywords and function calls when doing on paper, simple words are enough. Another debugging technique is to insert intermediate printouts, logging what the program is doing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All recursive methods need a base case (to exit the recursion). Additionally it helps if you can see progress on the recursion happening at every step. Note that you weren't recursing when the maxindex pointed to a value less than last.

This is one way to correct your issues in `rec_ssort`:

```
void rec_ssort(int arr[], int len) {
  // base case: if we're looking at an empty array we're done.
  if (len <= 0) return;

  int last = len - 1;
  int maxindex = max_index(arr, 0, last);
  if (arr[maxindex] > arr[last]) {
    swap(arr, maxindex, last);
  } 

  // recursively call with a shorter len
  rec_ssort(arr, last);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, let me try this out. Thank you for reponse!

Comment: You seemed to have cut down the amount of code I wrote down by more than 50%.. this is upsetting for me since i didn't think it could be done like that ...I'm still trying to grasp what you did here.

Comment: The recursion is always reducing the size of the array. At each step you're swapping the largest element to the end of the array. It would also be valid to drop the `last` variable, call `max_index(arr, 0, len)` and then call `rec_ssort(arr, len - 1)`, and drop your if comparison, to more easily see what's happening. Pseudocode: find largest element, put it at end of the array, and sort the array minus the newly found largest element.